# Why setting expireAfterAccess does not work?

Tags: java, caching, testing, guava

Why does the `timedCachetest` fails on the last line? Why cache is not empty after 60 seconds?

```
package com.test.cache;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.cache.Cache;
import com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder;

public class CacheTest {
    private static final int MAXIMUM_SIZE = 10;
    private static final int CONCURRENCY_LEVEL = 1;
    private static final long EXPIRE_AFTER_ACCESS = 60;
    Cache<String, Thing> cache;
    private static TimeUnit unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;
    private static long sec = 1000;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(MAXIMUM_SIZE).concurrencyLevel(CONCURRENCY_LEVEL).expireAfterAccess(EXPIRE_AFTER_ACCESS, unit).build();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        cache = null;
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleCachetest() {
        String key = "key";
        Integer hc = key.hashCode();
        Thing thing = new Thing(key);
        cache.put(key, thing);
        thing = cache.getIfPresent(key);
        Assert.assertNotNull(thing);
        Assert.assertEquals(hc, thing.getValue());
        Assert.assertEquals(key, thing.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, cache.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void timedCachetest() {
        String key = "key";
        Thing thing = new Thing(key);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, cache.size());
        cache.put(key, thing);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, cache.size());
        try {
            thing = cache.getIfPresent(key);
            long millis = 100 * sec;
            Thread.sleep(millis);
            // cache.invalidateAll();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Assert.assertNotNull(thing);
        Assert.assertEquals(key, thing.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, cache.size());
    }

    class Thing {
        public Thing(String key) {
            this.name = key;
            this.value = key.hashCode();
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        private String name;
        private Integer value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's stated right there in the `CacheBuilder` Javadoc:

> If expireAfterWrite or expireAfterAccess is requested entries may be evicted on each cache modification, on occasional cache accesses, or on calls to Cache.cleanUp(). Expired entries may be counted in Cache.size(), but will never be visible to read or write operations.

`CacheBuilder` caches do maintenance either when it's specifically requested, or when it can do so as part of a cache mutation, or occasionally on reads.  It doesn't e.g. start a thread to do cache maintenance, because a) threads are relatively heavyweight, and b) some environments restrict the creation of threads.

Comment: Thanks for reading the manual for me. ;) Maybe I should delete this question.